# Unflatten a flat array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a flat array like this and another flat array that describes the dimensions:

```
val elems = Array(0,1,2,3)
val dimensions = Array(2,2)
```

So now I must be able to unflatten that and return a 2*2 array like this:

```
val unflattened = {{0,1},{2,3}}
```

The dimensions could be of any order. The only condition is that the length of the flat array will equal to the product of the dimensions. So for example., if the dimensions is

> Array(3,3)

then I expect that the elems flat array will have to have 9 elements in it! The preconditions will be checked elsewhere so I do not have to worry about it here! All I need to do is to return an unflattened array.

Since this has to work on any dimension size, I think I probably have to define a recursive structure to put my results! Something like this?

```
case class Elem(elem: Array[Elem])
```

Could this work?

Any clue on how to go about implementing this function?

Comment: You need to think about how the results of this operation will be used. That will help clarify what result type you want which, in turn, will help clarify the algorithm you need to use to get that result.

Comment: The results will later be interpreted by another program. This function has to just take these 2 parameters and get the result back as the appropriate dimensionality!

Comment: So what is the format of "the results" that are interpreted by the other program? How is "the appropriate dimensionality" expressed in the data file?

Comment: I get what you mean. I could return an Object or an Any type and it is up to the caller to get the appropriate type. I could also pass back some information such that is the return type is an array and if so how many dimensions!

Comment: Could you have more than two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: @sparkr What output do you expect if the dimension is Array(2,3) ?

Comment: Do you mean true "3 dimensional" 3D array, 4D array ? Similar to what we have in dimensional reduction problems ?

Comment: Yes, I could have any dimensionality!

Comment: So for an array dimension (2,3), I expect a 2 dimensional array with 2 rows and 3 columns. The flat array would then contain a total of 6 elements in it!

Comment: For true 3D array, your flat array can not have 9 elements as the number has to be a  cube and a square. The example with 9 elements makes it feel like a 2D array with of size 3x3. If it is just a 2D array and your flat array is always of expected size, then you can just do a `grouped(n)` for a `n*m` array.

Comment: Ok so for a 3D array, I would have the dimensions like this: Array(2,2,2) for example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should be able to do this with a simple recursive structure, I went along with a structure more suited to the problem.

```
case class Row(elems: List[Int])

trait Matrix
case class SimpleMatrix(rows: List[Row]) extends Matrix
case class HigherMatrix(matrices: List[Matrix]) extends Matrix

// since your flat arrays are always of proper sizes... we are not handling error cases
// so we are dealing with higher N-dimension matrices with size List(s1, s2, ...,sN)
// I have chosen List for the example (as its easy to print), you should choose Array

def arrayToMatrix(flat: List[Int], dimension: Int, sizes: List[Int]): Matrix = dimension match {
  case 1 | 2 =>
    // since your flat arrays are always of proper sizes... there should not be any problems here
    SimpleMatrix(
      flat
        .grouped(sizes.head)
        .map(Row)
        .toList
    )
  case _ =>
    HigherMatrix(
      flat
        .grouped(sizes.tail.reduce(_ * _))
        .map(g => arrayToMatrix(g, dimension - 1, sizes.tail))
        .toList
    )
}

def arrayToSquareMatrix(flat: List[Int], dimension: Int, size: Int): Matrix =
  arrayToMatrix(flat, dimension, Range.inclusive(1, dimension).map(_ => size).toList)
```

Here are the examples

```
val sm_2__2_2 = arrayToSquareMatrix(Range.inclusive(1, 4).toList, 2, 2)
// sm_2__2_2: Matrix = SimpleMatrix(List(Row(List(1, 2)), Row(List(3, 4))))

val m_2__3_2 = arrayToMatrix(Range.inclusive(1, 6).toList, 2, List(3, 2))
// m_2__3_2: Matrix = SimpleMatrix(List(Row(List(1, 2, 3)), Row(List(4, 5, 6))))

val sm_3__2_2_2 = arrayToSquareMatrix(Range.inclusive(1, 8).toList, 3, 2)
// sm_3__2_2_2: Matrix = HigherMatrix(List(SimpleMatrix(List(Row(List(1, 2)), Row(List(3, 4)))), SimpleMatrix(List(Row(List(5, 6)), Row(List(7, 8))))))

val m_3__3_2_2 = arrayToMatrix(Range.inclusive(1, 12).toList, 3, List(3, 2, 2))
// m_3__3_2_2: Matrix = HigherMatrix(List(SimpleMatrix(List(Row(List(1, 2)), Row(List(3, 4)))), SimpleMatrix(List(Row(List(5, 6)), Row(List(7, 8)))), SimpleMatrix(List(Row(List(9, 10)), Row(List(11, 12))))))
```

Comment: The question is rather unclear, but idea is to allow a different size in each dimension not a single size in all dimensions.

Comment: @Tim even if that is required... we can easily tweak this to match that.

Comment: @Tim Updated to include any sizes in other dimensions.

Comment: What is the val sm_3__2? What is its dimension? To me it is a 3x2 matrix which means it should have 6 elements altogether in the flat structure, but your sample has 8 elements. So it should produce a Matrix of 3 rows and 2 columns, but you have a 4 row 2 column result. This is not correct!

Comment: `sm_3__2` is a square (cube to be more precise) `3-dimensional` matrix with sizes `2*2*2`, so it will have `8` elements. And `m_3__3_2_2` is a non-square `3-dimensional` matrix with sizes `3*2*2` so it has `12` elements. And yes there is an issue, fixing it.

Comment: Here is something similiar that has what exactly I want: https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/nd4j-matrix-manipulation The first example where a matrix is created and then transposed is exactly what I need!

Comment: Here is the reshape method that also does exactly what I want: https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/nd4j-matrix-manipulation

Comment: Fixed it. Works as expected now.

Comment: Can you fix / edit the example sm_3__2 as well? I't still is wrong! May be you forgot to edit it!

Comment: The `dimension` argument appears to duplicate the length of the `sizes` list.

Comment: I have added a new version to my answer using types inspired by the `Matrix` trait in this answer, if using `Any` is not acceptable.

Comment: `sm_3__2` is correct. it is a 2*2*2 matrics meaning a HigherMatrix containing 2 SimpleMatrix of 2*2.

Comment: Changed variable names to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
def unflatten(flat: Vector[Any], dims: Vector[Int]): Vector[Any] =
  if (dims.length <= 1) {
    flat
  } else {
    val (Vector(dim), rest) = dims.splitAt(1)

    flat.grouped(flat.length/dim).map(a => unflatten(a, rest)).toVector
  }
```

I have used `Vector` because `Array` isn't really a Scala type and doesn't allow conversion from `Array[Int]` to `Array[Any]`.

Note that this implements only one of the possible partitions with the given dimensions, so it may or may not be what is required.

---

This is a version using types based on the `Matrix` trait in another answer:

```
trait Matrix
case class SimpleMatrix(rows: Vector[Int]) extends Matrix
case class HigherMatrix(matrices: Vector[Matrix]) extends Matrix

def unflatten(flat: Vector[Int], dims: Vector[Int]): Matrix =
  if (dims.length <= 1) {
    SimpleMatrix(flat)
  } else {
    val (Vector(dim), rest) = dims.splitAt(1)

    val subs = flat.grouped(flat.length/dim).map(a => unflatten(a, rest)).toVector

    HigherMatrix(subs)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a function `grouped` on Arrays which does what you want.

```scala
@ Array(0,1,2,3).grouped(2).toArray
res2: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 3))
```

Comment: But this will not work for any number of dimensions, isn't?